# How to float two DIVs next to each other without specifying width?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to float two DIVs to the left, with the leftmost DIV having a set width and the rightmost DIV taking up the rest of the space. I thought this would work, but it's not:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        content left
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
    </div>

</div>

.container {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

.left {
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.right {
   float: left; 
   background-color: lightpink;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Zf3bd/3/)

I read a bunch of related questions on here, many of which suggested adding `overflow: hidden` to the parent container, but nothing I've tried has worked!

If I remove most of the lorem ipsum text to the point where there are just a few words (i.e. making the width less than the container), then the rightmost DIV floats to the left as expected.

How can I get this working?

Comment: is there a problem with just putting the left div inside the right one and setting its height to 100%, then setting the right to 100% width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second element in the flow should not float if you want it to cover all horizontal width avalaible.

To have it  stand aside and not behind as well , you need to trigger the layout. You can use  `overflow:hidden` for instance. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Zf3bd/4/)**

```
.container {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

.left {
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 400px;
}

.right {
   overflow:hidden;/* trigger layout to mind floatting elements inside and outside*/
   background-color: lightpink;
}
```

for colums of equal heights , you can use `display:table` on parent and `display:table-cell` on childs , remove all `float` rules in this case.

Comment: So the `overflow:hidden` on the DIV won't actually cause any of it's content to be hidden?

Comment: @Nate no, as long as you do not give any specific height or width. It will stands all the way aside the floatting element, it will not wrap under it if it goes further than bottom of floatting element.

Comment: @Nate actually, you can even skip the overflow:hidden if floatting element has a background: see the difference with content too wild http://jsfiddle.net/Zf3bd/6/, http://jsfiddle.net/Zf3bd/7/ . this kind of word doesn't exist, but if it is an image, you can set a max-width and it will follow the overflow rule if any . without max-width : http://jsfiddle.net/Zf3bd/8/ , http://jsfiddle.net/Zf3bd/9/ and with max-width: http://jsfiddle.net/Zf3bd/10/

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, no floating though:

```
.container {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.left {
  width: 50px;
  position:absolute;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.right {
  margin-left:50px;
  background-color: lightpink;
}
```